# Como trabalhar com UpdateView e Forms no template

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-1.8

Estou tentando renderizar os dados de um cliente no template, porém o gostaria de fazer sem utilizar `{{ form.as_p }}` ou `{{ form.as_table }}` whatever,gostaria de saber se tem alguma maneria de se utilizar o id dos clientes em questão e utilizar inputs no template no lugar de "form", já tentei de tudo aqui, sei que se entrar no shell do django consigo pegar o id apenas do form, porém mesmo com o id em mãos não consigo fazer com que o cliente seja renderizado para edição, os campos aparecem porém em branco.

**Detalhe**: Com CreateView este método de pegar os ids do form funcionou, porém quero que o mesmo aconteça com **UpdateView**.

Desde já agradeço a atenção.

Comment: Pq vc n quer usar o {{ form.as_p }}?  Existe alguma informação que vc não deseja mostrar?

Comment: Então Nathan, o que acontece de verdade e o seguinte, quero trabalhar com o layout do mesmo porém não estou conseguindo com form.as_p, estou utilizando bootstrap em todo o projeto porém estou parado ate hoje na parte do layout, como trabalhar com css em cima do form.as_p? estou com uma combobox também no mesmo, e não consegui um resultado favorável ao tentar implementar o css na mesma.

Comment: Bem, então o problema é a "apresentação" dos dados para o usuário? Se sim vc pode criar sua própria Form do Model, ao invés de apenas estender de forms.ModelForm vc pode dizer como cada tipo de dado deve ser mostrado e se deve ser ocultado.

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer apenas exibir os dados de um cliente em um template, você pode utilizar o DetailView

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview

```
class ClienteDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Cliente
    template_name = 'clientes/detail.html'
```

O problema de exibir os campos em branco, talvez seja porque na sua url você colocou algum outro parâmetro para o id, e não pk.

```
#urls.py
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/editar/$', ClienteUpdateView.as_view(), name='cliente_update'),

#views
class ClienteUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Cliente
    form_class = ClienteForm
    template_name = 'clientes/update.html'


#listagem de clientes
...
   <a href="{% url 'clientes:cliente_update' pk=cliente.id %}">Editar</a>
...
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview